# Problem using like button in application profile tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have an application profile for my application. I am trying to use a like button. But it is does not work.

```
<fb:like layout="button_count" href="http://fbrell.com"></fb:like>
```

But share button works fine. Like button works fine on canvas page.

Am i missing something.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The entire body of FBML is not available in every place where FBML is allowed.

So, in short, "no" you are not missing something.  Certain elements are just not allowed in certain places.

Unfortunately, this isn't documented terribly well in any one place - it used to be easier to test when they still had the FBML Test Console, but that tool has been removed.

However, you *should* see FBML rendering errors at the bottom of the page.  Check again and make sure you didn't overlook them.